# What to do if a problem returns back?

Tags: discussion

The first few weeks after installing Ubuntu 14.04 I struggled with abnormally high battery discharge rates. I set up [a question on the issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/461620/177437), and although good answers poped up, this abnormal behaviour dragged on. One day the updates brought energy consumption back to normal and I marked the issue as solved.

But last week another round of updates brought back the problem, the battery discharge rate is now worse than ever. How would you suggest to deal with this reappearance:

- Open a new question, since it likely refers to a different software build?
- Re-open the original question, by unmarking the accepted answer?
- Left the accepted answer marked but expand the question with fresh details?

Frankly, none of these options seem very satisfying. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think that, since an update caused your battery to drain, it's most likely a bug. I would post it on launchpad if you have info about what is going on.